# CGI with Tkinter python3

Tags: python, tkinter, cgi

Is it possible to use **TkInter** with cgi and run it on localhost?

I can not import TkInter and Matplotlib when I am using cgi and run it with `localhost/cgi-bin/index.py`

**Error that I get :**

[image]

Comment: Can you try to paste that error message here as actual text, rather than as an image link? It looks like your Python isn't configured correctly for Tkinter. Does the server have Tcl/Tk? I expect that Tkinter _isn't_ normally installed / configured on a Web server, since it doesn't make much sense for a non-local browser page to create a GUI on the server. :) What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: No, you cannot use tkinter with a web server.

Comment: What can I use then as python GUI on web?